# Тактового ударения не существует? Если ли вообще смысл в учебниках и статьях про это?

Tags: тактовое-ударение, логическое-ударение

Будем считать логическим ударением ударение в предложениях:

> Трампа забанила ЧАСТНАЯ компания. (Ударение на ‟частная”.)
> Это ЖЕНСКИЙ туалет. (Когда мужчина находится в женском туалете и кто-то возмущён. Ударение на ‟женский”.)

То есть когда человек имеет некие специфические причины выделить некое слово, когда это слово произносится более громко и ударная гласная этого слова произносится более затянуто. Отмечу, что такое ударение является крайне редким в речи, в большинстве предложений вообще нет такого ударения. Если взять какое-нибудь предложение, например: ‟Вася пошёл в магазин”, то здесь нет логического ударения – нет каких-то специфических причин выделить какое-то слово, никакое слово не произносится более громко, никакая ударная гласная не тянется.

Но что такое тактовое ударение? Существует ли оно? Возьмём два предложения:

> Он был скрытен и хитёр, как лис. (Задумано, что обе характеристики – скрытен и хитёр – относятся к ‟как лис”.)
> Он был силён и быстр, как пантера. (Задумано, что только ‟быстр” относится к ‟как пантера”.)

Интонационная разница между этими предложениями в том, как слова объединяются в пучки, где между словами пучка одинаково короткая пауза, которая короче пауз по краям пучка. В первом предложении два однородных входят в один пучок – ‟скрытен и хитёр”, а во втором только один однородный член входит в пучок – ‟быстр, как пантера”. Мы видим, что интонационная разница зависит от объединения слов в пучки, что, в свою очередь, зависит от пауз между словами. Где же здесь место какому-то ударению? На какое слово падает тактовое ударение в пучке ‟скрытен и хитёр”? Если на ‟хитёр”, то почему не на ‟скрытен”. А как это определяется, то есть по длине произношения ударной гласной или как? Какие вообще существуют наблюдаемые характеристики этого самого тактового ударения?

На форуме есть человек, который часто использует этот термин в своих ответах. Вот он наверняка мне поможет разобраться. От него я жду ответ больше всего. Наконец-то разберусь!

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ К ВОПРОСУ ПОСЛЕ ОДНОГО КОММЕНТАРИЯ**
Если вдруг то ударение, о котором я писал в начале вопроса, не логическое ударение по общепринятой терминологии, то напишите также об этом, напишите, какое это ударение, и напишите, что такое логическое ударение. Пока мне не объяснят, какое это ударение (логическое, эмфатическое, фразовое, какое-то другое), я буду называть его ударением Святого Иосифа.

**ЕЩЁ ОДНО ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**
Я так понимаю, этот человек не будет отвечать на мой вопрос. А тогда у меня закрадываются справедливые подозрения, что он вообще сам не знает, что же такое это ударение, он сам не понимал, что писал, когда использовал этот термин. Это довольно распространённая ситуация для лингвистики, когда лингвист сам не знает, что он пишет. Я заподозрил это и, похоже, оказался прав. Я бы хотел, чтобы этот человек либо доказал, что он понимал, что пишет, либо удалил все свои ответы с использование этого термина.

Comment: Это не форум. Это энциклопедия в виде вопросов и ответов, по информации модератора.

Comment: Вы уже почти догадались, что происходит, осталось связать то, что вы увидели с причиной этого "ударения". И мне кажется, название "логическое" ударение тут очень подходит, я бы его еще назвал "формальным" ударением. Кстати, тоже из этой серии)

Comment: Добавлю пару слов... Лучше использовать ОБЩЕПРИНЯТУЮ терминологию, ведь все ударения (фразовое, тактовое, логическое и т.д. ) имеют определения во всех учебниках по ФОНЕТИКЕ, и именно они используются в других материалах по смежным темам. Вообще говоря, начинать «науку» с собственных определений – это значит создавать ее лично для себя, своих учеников и  последователей в будущем. Что ж, задача непростая и ответственная, не каждому по плечу…))  Но кто такими научными выводами и суждениями сейчас будет пользоваться?

Comment: @Sharon я буду, я за любой кипишь, кроме голодовки, в добрый путь!)

Comment: Ну прочитали бы из любопытства, а дальше? Пользоваться-то как?)) P.S. А я – кипиш или нет?)

Comment: Могло бы возникнуть недопонимание, если бы я просто использовал термин ‟логическое ударение” с собственным определением, НО Я ЖЕ ПОЛ ВОПРОСА ПОСВЯТИЛ ОПИСАНИЮ ТОГО, ЧТО ПОНИМАЮ ПОД ЭТИМ ТЕРМИНОМ! Я же описал, о каком ударении идёт речь, поэтому не возникнет никакого недопонимания. Если это не логическое, а эмфатическое ударение, то напишите об этом. Если я перед началом разговора описываю, о каком ударении идёт речь, то я могу называть это хоть ударением Святого Иосифа. Просто нелепейшие претензии от вас. И это вообще вопрос о том, где какое ударение.

Comment: @Sharon конечно, вы разве не чувствуете мою поддержку)

Comment: хотя меня похоже игнорируют, ну да ладно)

Comment: @Буратино  А я-то думала вы меня поддерживаете по зову души, по велению сердца...))  И я вас не игнорирую, внимательно читаю.

Comment: Вы так мучаетесь. Ладно, проанализировал, высота слова с ударением выше. Достаточно сравнить "хитрый, как лис" и "хитрый как лис".